# ajax not showing html data

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

> //view ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]
>           ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
                  $(document).ready(function() {  

                     $.ajax({  
                         url: "<?= site_url('products/getallvariance') ?>", 
                      type:"GET",
                      dataType:"html",
                         success:function(data){ 
                         alert('fahad');
                       //  alert(data);  
                            $('#prTable2').html(data);  
                     }  
                     ,error: function(data)

                     {
                     alert (data);
                     }
                  });  

            });  
</script>  

//controller get value from the model but not showing data into view through ajax. ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]
function getallvariance()
    {

        $variance['allvariance'] = $this->products_model->getvariance();

        $output = '<tbody>';

      foreach ($variance['allvariance'] as $row)  
      {  

         $output .= '<tr><td colspan="10" class=" sorting_1">'.$row->name.'</td></tr>';  
      }
      $output .= '</tbody>';

      echo $output; 

    }

//model is the query is correct? ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object] ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]ajax not return data from the controller. View returns [object], [object]

function getvariance()
{
    $this->db->select('name,  IFNULL( quantity, 0 ) AS quantity');
    $q = $this->db->from('products');

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Where is your model code?? and check your console what error it shows??

Comment: function getvariance()
{
    $this->db->select('name,  IFNULL( quantity, 0 ) AS quantity');
    $q = $this->db->from('products');

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return FALSE;
}

Comment: please put this code in your question

Comment: model is already there

Comment: You're not getting your DB results. `$q = $this->db->from('products')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Your model function always `return FALSE` because you are not get data and you use two time `foreach() loop` one in your `model` and other in your `controller` that's wrong in your code. It would be

**Model**

```
<?php

function getvariance() {
    $this->db->select('name,  IFNULL( quantity, 0 ) AS quantity');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $q= $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
function getallvariance() {
    $this->load->model('products_model');// load your model
    $variance = $this->products_model->getvariance();
    if($variance){

    $output = '<tbody>';

    foreach ($variance as $row) {

        $output .= '<tr><td colspan="10" class=" sorting_1">' . $row->name . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</tbody>';
    }else{
    $output="error";
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: have you load your model file in your constructor

Comment: $this->page_construct('products/update_price', $meta, $output); like this?

Comment: yes problem occurs in ajax when getting data into html form